# How to create a list of the dictionaries in Golang?

Tags: json, list, dictionary, go

I'm a newbie in Golang.

I'm going to create a list of dictionaries that is resizable (this is not static) with append some `dict` to the `list`. Then I want to write it on a file, but I was confused.

I want something like this:

```
[
 {"port": 161, "timeout": 1, "sleep_time": 5, "metrics": [
  {"tag_name": "output_current", "id": 3},
  {"tag_name": "input_voltage", "id": 2}
 ]},
 {"port": 161, "timeout": 1, "sleep_time": 4, "metrics": [
   {"tag_name": "destructor", "id": 10}
 ]}
]
```

---

[UPDATE]:

What is the `.append()` Python equivalent in Go language like the following code snippet?

```
list_ = []
dict_ = {"key": val}
list_.append(dict_)
```

I've found the answer to this section ([UPDATE]) by borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53846458/3702377):

```
type Dictionary map[string]interface{}
data := []Dictionary{}
dict1 := Dictionary{"key": 1}
dict2 := Dictionary{"key": 2}
data = append(data, dict1, dict2)
```

Comment: Have you looked at slices and maps?

Comment: Yes, I did it. So does not exist list and dict in Golang? What is the equivalent in Go?

Comment: _This is my slice, and this is my map. This is for list, and this is for dict._ (sorry couldn't help it). Anyhow, "a list of dicts" translates to "a slice of maps" in Go (I'd also consider struct).

Comment: Please walk through the [tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org) it [covers](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/15) the `append` part, too.

Comment: @bereal Thanks for the guidance, I want to create a list of dictionaries which is not static, then write it on a file. Is this possible with the slice and map?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. With a help from [`json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) and [`ioutil`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/).

Comment: @bereal I'll check it (I've worked with `ioutil`), Thanks.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari: Just an FYI, just like python has `.append`, golang has a built-in function called `append(target []interface{}, elements ...interface{}) []interface{}`. Just read through the documentation and you'll find it

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need the data to be stored in a slice of dictionary/key-value-based format, then using the combination of slice and `map[string]interface{}` is enough.

In this example below, I created a new type called `Dictionary`, to avoid writing too many `map[string]interface{}` syntax on composite literals.

```
type Dictionary map[string]interface{}

data := []Dictionary{
    {
        "metrics": []Dictionary{
            { "tag_name": "output_current", "id": 3 },
            { "tag_name": "input_voltage", "id": 2 },
        },
        "port":       161,
        "timeout":    1,
        "sleep_time": 5,
    },
    {
        "metrics": []Dictionary{
            { "tag_name": "destructor", "id": 10 },
        },
        "port":       161,
        "timeout":    1,
        "sleep_time": 4,
    },
}
```

---

However if your data structure is fixed, then I suggest to use a struct instead `map`. Below is an another example as above, using same dataset but leveraging struct instead of `map`:

```
type Metric struct {
    TagName string `json:"tag_name"`
    ID      int    `json:"id"`
}

type Data struct {
    Port      int      `json:"port"`
    Timeout   int      `json:"timeout"`
    SleepTime int      `json:"sleep_time"`
    Metrics   []Metric `json:"metrics"`
}

data := []Data{
    Data{
        Port:      161,
        Timeout:   1,
        SleepTime: 5,
        Metrics: []Metric{
            Metric{TagName: "output_current", ID: 3},
            Metric{TagName: "input_voltage", ID: 2},
        },
    },
    Data{
        Port:      161,
        Timeout:   1,
        SleepTime: 4,
        Metrics: []Metric{
            Metric{TagName: "destructor", ID: 10},
        },
    },
}
```

---

#### Update 1

To be able to write the `data` in JSON file, the particular `data` needs to be converted into JSON string first. Use `json.Marshal()` to do the conversion from `map` data (or struct object data) into JSON string format (in `[]byte` type).

```
buf, err := json.Marshal(data)
if err !=nil {
    panic(err)
}

err = ioutil.WriteFile("fileame.json", buf, 0644)
if err !=nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Then use `ioutil.WriteFile()` to write it into file.

---

If you somehow need to print the JSON data as a string, then cast the `buf` into `string` type.

```
jsonString := string(buf)
fmt.Println(jsonString)
```

Statements above will generate output below:

```
[{"port":161,"timeout":1,"sleep_time":5,"metrics":[{"tag_name":"output_current","id":"3"},{"tag_name":"input_voltage","id":"2"}]},{"port":161,"timeout":1,"sleep_time":4,"metrics":[{"tag_name":"destructor","id":"10"}]}]
```

Comment: Thanks for response +1, that makes sense.

Comment: So finally, How can I store this slice of maps (list of dicts) on a file? I tried it using this: `ioutil.WriteFile("config.json", data, 0644)` but I got this error: 'cannot use data (type []Dictionary) as type []byte in argument to ioutil.WriteFile
' How can I write this as s json file?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari please take a look at updated answer

Comment: I'm going to accept this, with an edit about some redundant `Dictionary`- I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @BenyaminJafari np, glad it helps :-)

Answer (score 5):

So the types you are looking for are:

```
dict => map
list => slice
```

A simple example of a map looks like:

```
m:=map[string]int{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2,
}
```

A simple example of a slice looks like:

```
var s []int
s = append(s, 1)
s = append(s, 2, 3)
```

So to put that together for your type:

```
[]map[string]interface{}{
    {
        "port":       161,
        "timeout":    1,
        "sleep_time": 5,
        "metrics": []map[string]interface{}{
            {"tag_name": "output_current", "id": "3"},
            {"tag_name": "input_voltage", "id": "2"},
        },
    },
    {
        "port":       161,
        "timeout":    1,
        "sleep_time": 4,
        "metrics": []map[string]interface{}{
            {"tag_name": "destructor", "id": "10"},
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I got this error: `cannot use map[string]int literal (type map[string]int) as type map[string][]string in assignment
` in your simple example of `map`.

Comment: Change `map[string]int` to `map[string][]string`

Comment: What's mean of `interface`? Is it that means any type?

Comment: An empty interface does (e.g., `interface{}`). Take a look at https://tour.golang.org/methods/14